# ggplot2: how to change the width of colour aesthetic in a bar/col geometry?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a column/barplot, where I change the `fill` aesthetic (inner colour of bar) with one variable, and the `colour` aesthetic (colour around the bar) with another variable. The colour around the bar is not easy to see, so I would like to increase the width of that bar. How can I do that? I don't see any `width` argument in `scale_color_manual`?

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, p = 1:5, q = factor(1:5),
                  r = factor(1:5))
data <-  data_frame(x = rep("a", 4),
                    y = c(1,2,4,3),
                    categ = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                    group = rep(c("a", "b"), each=2))

ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill= categ, colour=group)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `size` argument

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill= categ, colour=group)) + 
  geom_col(size=3) +   ### change
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

yielding this:

[image]

Comment: @Matifou My pleasure, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Rutilities has a "font" function with a host of different fonts identified numerically.  For example (font = "11"). Add right into your script and you should be on your way.